# Query application event log between a certain time period

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am trying to query application event log for a certain time period in order to check a specific event which confirms the backup status of an application. Since the backup schedule is set between 10:00 PM and 11:00 PM, I am trying to get info about event id 18264.

I use:

```
gwmi -computername somename -namespace root\cimv2 -query "Select EventCode from Win32_NTLogEvent where LogFile = 'Application' and EventCode = '18264'"
```

Now, what happens is that I get more than one output. I want to limit the output to 1 which is based on the latest. Example; get event id for yesterday between 10 PM and 11 PM. I see a column as TimeWritten. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are specific cmdlets for reading event logs, these are much easier than using WMI. Eg.

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName comp1,comp2 `
             -FilterHashtable @{LogName='application'; 
                                starttime=([datetime]::today.AddDays(-1)); 
                                endtime=([datetime]::Today);
                                id=1704}
```

(line breaks added for clarity)

This will return all event #1704 from computers `comp1` and `comp2` from yesterday. Looks at the help for `Get-WinEvent`'s `FilterHashtable` parameter (`get-help get-WinEvent -param FilterHashtable`) for more search criteria (eg. you can pass multiple log names and ids).

There is also a `-MaxEvents` parameter to limit the output to a number of events.

Comment: This cmdlet only works on Windows Vista and onwards. I forgot to mention that the environment is set to XP and Server 2003. All Servers are 2003 :( I am using PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: @Rajiv: in that case look at `Get-EventLog -computerName c1 -logname application ...` (see the help for the full list of parameters). You'll need to use `Where-Object` to filter by event id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom XPath query which can be used further in PowerShell, C# to query or watch event logs.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4 or Level=0 or Level=5) and (EventID=18264) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 3600000]]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```